# Can't update chromedriver and seleniumrelease

Tags: selenium, cmd, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I try to work with protractor. So I followed a small tutorial and the first thing I did:

```
npm install -g protractor
```

This will install two command line tools, protractor and webdriver-manager.
But now I have to update my webdriver-manager:

```
webdriver-manager update
```

So my cmd tries to connect with https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/chromedriver_win32.zip and https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar.
But it will give this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testnew>webdriver-manager update
Updating selenium standalone
downloading https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/selenium-server
-standalone-2.45.0.jar...
Updating chromedriver
downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/chromedriver_win32.
zip...
Error: Got error Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN from https://selenium-release.stor
age.googleapis.com/2.45/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
Error: Got error Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN from https://chromedriver.storage.
googleapis.com/2.14/chromedriver_win32.zip
```

Sometimes it is the EAI_AGAIN error and sometimes ENOTFOUND.
But what I don't understand is that I can download the zip and the jar manually in my browser. When I surf to the URL it all works fine. But not in the cmd. Can someone help me?
PS: pinging isn't possible to the url's

Update: after proxy settings I get this error:

```
Error: Got error Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket
hang up from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/chromedriver_win32
.zip
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If setting your proxy does not work, how it happened to me, you can download the files manually from the urls show in the console, and put them into the selenium folder

The path in Windows is:

`users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium`

That works for me.

I hope that helps

Comment: Maybe you'll need to download some specific driver too

Comment: After this running  webdriver-manager start, results in error : E/start - Selenium Standalone is not present. Install with webdriver-manager update --standalone

Answer (score 18):

It happened the same to me. The problem was due to a proxy we are using inside our company.

`webdriver-manager` has a parameter which is `--proxy`, where you can specify the proxy which the webdriver command should use.
The proxy configuration which you might have in nmp (.npmrc file in your users dicrectory) won't work for webdriver-manager.

Here the example which worked out for me.

```
webdriver-manager --proxy http://yourproxy:8080 update
```

Answer (score 2):

> Read on if your *webdriver-manager update* doesn't update chromedriver
>   to the latest.

I lost a few weeks pulling my hair around an issue I had with `"Unable to discover open pages"` and every time I would update the chromedriver, it would update to `version 2.22` for chromedriver and I believe the selenium server to `v2.53`. 
My problem wasn't really with the selenium server so v2.53 was fine.

```
Issue was with chromedriver v2.22.
```

Eventhough [this chromdriver link](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) showed that there was a latest version of 2.24, `'webdriver-manager update'` would NOT pick up that latest version, it would only grab version 2.22 of the chrome driver.

> How did I go around this?

Simply run the command below after you check this link for which version of chromedriver you want to update to; for instance, I wanted v2.24 so I ran the command below:

> webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.24

If you check your location: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\`

You should see that the desired chromedriver was downloaded there; if it's not there, read the command prompt logs and it'll tell you where it downloaded your chromdriver files.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Your web browser is probably using a proxy, or some other indirect access to the wider internet that the `webdriver-manager` script isn't configured to use.  (The `webdriver-manager` supports a `--proxy` parameter if you know what to pass to it.)

If you can download the files manually, just put them in the selenium directory manually.  The script also unzips the "chromedriver_win32.zip" in place to get the `chromedriver` binary contained in it.

Comment: How can I find my proxy or should I configure it by myself? So you have to use a proxy? My settings says: use proxysettings from the system. And after that I have to do this? npm config set proxy http://<proxy.com>:port. HTTP_PROXY=http://'your http proxy ip':'your proxy port', set HTTPS_PROXY=http://'your https proxy ip':'your proxy port'. It works for a friend: who had the setting: manually configured proxy (but he never dit that). I did the same as he had and now I'm getting this error: 
Error: Got error Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket
hang up from...

Comment: Configuring an HTTP proxy depends on your network configuration.  The proxy configuration is only necessary if there is a network proxy between your computer and the internet.  I am guessing that there is one that your web browser understands because of the error you are getting.  Again, if downloading the files works through the web browser, that is probably good enough.