# protractor-webdriver-manager-update-occurs-events-js161 - throw er

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm facing below error while I try to update Web-driver manager after installing protractor

I have no idea what is obstructing here. Can anyone help me out?

> ```
> events.js:161
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>   ^
>   Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com
> ```
>
> selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com:443at errnoException
>   (dns.js:28:10)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)

Answer (score 1):

It happened the same to me. The problem was due to a proxy.

```
webdriver-manager --proxy http://yourproxy:8080 update
```

This worked for me. For more check this link 
[Can't update chromedriver and seleniumrelease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483126/cant-update-chromedriver-and-seleniumrelease)

Comment: `--ignore_ssl` flag could be useful if you get certificate error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a (company) proxy?

Try to set your win proxy in cmd with:

set http_proxy=**http**://proxy:port

set https_proxy=**http**://proxy:port

important is that you use **http** and not **https**